# Using TabHost include other layout

Tags: android, user-interface, android-tabhost

I have a TabHost layout (the below code)

```
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myTabHost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp" >
    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="65dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I am loading some activities inside the TabHost and every things about the activities are OK. but my problem is about loading another layout at the top of TabHost via Include tag, 
in other layouts like LinearLayout i put a include tag inside it and it was OK, but in TabHost i could not do like that because after adding include the TabHost UI gets corrupted
.
please tell me how to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `TabHost` tag with another `LinearLayout` tag like this:

```
<LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <!-- inclde goes here -->
            <TabHost
                android:id="@+id/myTabHost"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                        <!-- Other tags as you have already. -->
            </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Then Place the `LinearLayout` as a parent to `TabHost` and include that `LinearLayout` using include tag in other `layouts` as below:

```
   <LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/myTabHost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp" >
    </TabWidget>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="65dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
    </TabHost>
 </LinearLayout>
```